# Creating console application using C# and connect to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

Help me create a console application that will call a certain webservice and needs to add SQL query on it. I don't know how to proceed.

Console App:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SharepointDataCleanUp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)


        {
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the webservice I would want to connect:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;

using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Uniliver.Components.DocumentManagement
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Summary description for DocumentsManagementService. 
    /// This service exposes 4 methods: Upload, Update, Get and Delete.
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class DocumentsManagementService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


--Methods

Upload

Edit

Get

Delete

}
```

Also, below is the sample query that i would want to add to my console app.

```
Select * from Customers
```

Comment: what have you tried? it sounds like you need a method that allows you to return a list of all the customers, eg a `List` method.

Comment: If you're stuck this early in the process, perhaps it's best to follow a tutorial first - they should give you a feeling for what steps you'll need to take in your project.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely stuck now. The listed methods above are readily available but I'm in trouble, I don't know how would I call it on my console app. I need to call the Get method that will allow me to get all the returned results for the query. I dont know what to do now.